# something went wrong with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION?

Tags: php

i have this problem when im trying to upload a file to amazon s3, it gives me this error but i dnt seem to understand:

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /var/www/vhosts/??????/httpdocs/actions/S3.php on line 1257
```

Comment: i disabled safe_mode but im still getting the error, im using 1and1 :)) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is exactly what is says in the error message - you have safe_mode or open_basedir enabled in php.ini.  Either edit php.ini to disable whichever one of those you have on, or don't use PHP's flavor of curl. If you can't edit php.ini you'll have to find a new host or find a new solution.

Comment: hey i disbaled both safe_mode and open_basedir to Off, but its till not working and giving me same errors

Comment: Have you checked the output of phpinfo() to see if they are actually turned off?  (Relevant documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php )

Answer (score 2):

There is a lengthy workaround posted in the comments to the curl functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102121

Though the better solution would be not to use cURL. (See PEAR Http_Request2 or Zend_Http for alternatives, or use PHPs built-in HttpRequest if available.)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to get a new host.  [`open_basedir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) isn't a great security feature (a good host will use the far better approach of setting up a jail).  [`safe_mode`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) is deprecated.  So the best result will come from disabling both directives (or finding a new host if yours is unwilling to do so).

However, if that's not an option, you can always implement something like [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102121) (from a comment on php.net)...

Answer (score 0):

i have shorter and less safe variant of workaround posted by mario, but you may find it useful for urls with known number of redirects (for example FB Graph API image calls -- graph.facebook.com/4/picture)

```
function cURLRequest($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result) {
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    } else if (empty($result)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        // PHP safe mode fallback for 302 redirect
        if (!empty($info['http_code']) && !empty($info['redirect_url'])) {
            return cURLRequest($info['redirect_url']);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this version of Curl

```
//=================== compressed version===============(https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/)
function get_remote_data($url, $post_paramtrs=false)    {   $c = curl_init();curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); if($post_paramtrs){curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=bla&".$post_paramtrs );}  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0"); curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'CookieName1=Value;'); curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);  $follow_allowed= ( ini_get('open_basedir') || ini_get('safe_mode')) ? false:true;  if ($follow_allowed){curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);}curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 9);curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);         curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');$data=curl_exec($c);$status=curl_getinfo($c);curl_close($c);preg_match('/(http(|s)):\/\/(.*?)\/(.*\/|)/si',  $status['url'],$link);$data=preg_replace('/(src|href|action)=(\'|\")((?!(http|https|javascript:|\/\/|\/)).*?)(\'|\")/si','$1=$2'.$link[0].'$3$4$5', $data);$data=preg_replace('/(src|href|action)=(\'|\")((?!(http|https|javascript:|\/\/)).*?)(\'|\")/si','$1=$2'.$link[1].'://'.$link[3].'$3$4$5', $data);if($status['http_code']==200) {return $data;} elseif($status['http_code']==301 || $status['http_code']==302) { if (!$follow_allowed){if(empty($redirURL)){if(!empty($status['redirect_url'])){$redirURL=$status['redirect_url'];}}   if(empty($redirURL)){preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)(\r|\n)/si', $data, $m);if (!empty($m[2])){ $redirURL=$m[2]; } } if(empty($redirURL)){preg_match('/href\=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)here\<\/a\>/si',$data,$m); if (!empty($m[1])){ $redirURL=$m[1]; } }   if(!empty($redirURL)){$t=debug_backtrace(); return call_user_func( $t[0]["function"], trim($redirURL), $post_paramtrs);}}} return "ERRORCODE22 with $url!!<br/>Last status codes<b/>:".json_encode($status)."<br/><br/>Last data got<br/>:$data";}
```